# NestJS env variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, dotenv

I'm trying to set configuration variables on my project using the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).

I added the following line to my app.module.ts imports:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  isGlobal: true
}),
```

I created a .env file at the root of my project with the following content:

```
MY_VARIABLE=myself
```

And I use dependecy injection to get access to the configuration service:

```
constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
```

However the following line logs 'Env variable: undefined'

```
console.log('Env variable: ', this.configService.get<any>('MY_VARIABLE'));
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got it set up properly. Can you share a reproduction? In the snippets you've provided I can't see a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several scenarios:

- You don't have `.env` file
- `.env` is incorrectly defined
- You're trying to access environmental variables from `.env` located outside the server's root path
- You need to install `dotenv` package
- Deploying to Serverless and in the `functions` (or other deployable folder) the `.env` is missing (even though it's in the root location it has to be there too)